# I am not able to display View properly in codeigniter. Using foreach loop I have been trying

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here you can view the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcApq.png)

Here is my controller:-

```
public function order_info()
{
    $this->load->model('customize_model');
   $data['user'] = $this->customize_model->order_info();
   $data['product']=$this->customize_model->order_info();
   $data['sale'] = $this->customize_model->order_info();
    $this->load->view('custom/order',$data);
}
```

And here is my modal:-

```
 public function order_info()
  {
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *
    FROM user
    JOIN product
    ON user.user_id = product.product_id 
    JOIN sale
    ON user.user_id = sale.buyer
    ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 100;");   
    return $query;
 }
```

This is view:-

```
<?php foreach($sale->result() as $row)
   {
      $order_id = $row->sale_id;                                 
      $grand_total = $row->grand_total;
      $status = $row->status;
  ?>
      <tr>     
         <td><?php echo $order_id;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $username;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $productname?></td>
         <td><?php echo $grand_total;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $status;?></td>     
       </tr> 
       <?php 
         foreach($user->result() as $row1)
         {
          $username = $row1->username;  
          foreach($product->result() as $row2)
          {
            $productname = $row2->title;                                  
           }
          }
        }
 ?>
```

Here in my view I got stuck with displaying records, in single table.
problem is in view. foreach loop doesn't work in this format which shall i use to solve it.

Comment: Your code is messy in controller didn't look like it needed 3 queries as it has same output. Anyway, please update the question to show your current output and what you need in view.

Comment: I have shared output link just checkout hope you'll get question clearly.

Comment: Is your problem regarding first entry being empty. If it is the same that's because you are printing it first before defining. Be more descriptive in what is your requirement and what is improper with the above output image.

Comment: In the above output image username and product name are printing same for every user id.

Comment: Your controller seems to be running same query why don't you get username and title from the first loop rather than setting a variable. just write  $row->username; in td instead of $username variable same for title.

Comment: Could you just edit the code?, so that I can understand how actually it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this in your view:-

```js
<?php foreach($sale->result() as $row)
   {
      $order_id = $row->sale_id;                                 
      $grand_total = $row->grand_total;
      $status = $row->status;
  ?>
      <tr>     
         <td><?php echo $order_id;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->username; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->title; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $grand_total;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $status;?></td>     
       </tr> 
       <?php 
        }
 ?>
```

Comment: Im new to programming could you suggest any better resources to understand to working flow of logic.

Comment: Play around with small pieces of code, try to make and break the code. You'll only learn from experience.

Comment: Hi I have got some doubt in the same problem.

Comment: What is the doubt?

Comment: how to assign selected option value to jquery variable and pass through ajax to controller , and how to recieve the current selected option in controller(codeigniter).

Comment: Do some research of your own. Then still if you are not able to get the solution post a new question like above with your code.

Comment: Hi @shubhamkakade , Can you share any good resources to understand the codeigniter and mysql projects.